# Why are some Windows WMI counters available on some systems and not on others?

Tags: windows, wmi

I am trying to measue CPU use per process with:

```
typeperf "\Process(SOME PROCESS)\% Processor Time" -si 1 -sc 60
```

The problem is that I have to do that on quite a few PCs and here problems start. Some machines return the following error:

```
Error: No valid counters
```

For example I am using exactly the same command shown above and get:

```
PC_A (Win7 64bit Home Edition) - type perf works
PC_B (Win7 64bit Pro Edition) - typeperf works
PC_C (Win7 64bit Pro Edition) - Error: No valid counters
PC_D (WinXP 32bit Multimedia Ed) - typeperf works
PC_E (Win Vista 64bit)  - Error: No valid counters
```

I've spent a lot of time on that and would appreciate if someone could clarify why:

1. What is the root of these discrapencies? After all I use the same command.
2. Why does it work on 2 Win7s and not on the third one?
3. Can 'missing' performance counters be enabled / turned on somehow?

BTW - I have admin rights on all these machines.

Thanks,
Artur

Answer (score 0):

Check if the computers where you cannot read the counters are using the same language pack. I have seen this fail on systems with other language packs installed where the counters must be accessed with their localized names.

Comment: All use English. BW - I've found the solution "lodctr.exe /R" helped.